# Как затереть введённые значения на консоль , оставлять только результат потока вывода

Tags: c++, windows

У меня есть код , где пользователь вводит значения , стоки.

Цикл while обрабатывает все набранные значения за один проход, поясню.
Например , пользователь вводит:

```
23
12.4
Apple

результат: 23 , 12.4 , Apple
```

и продолжаем набирать далее пока не выйдем из цикла с помощью ^Z.

Можно ли затереть набранные пользователем значения , оставив только результат не меняя тело цикла?

Comment: @Abyx OC Windows

Comment: @Abyx переместить курсор в произвольную позицию можно через SetConsoleCursorPosition

Comment: @Abyx есть GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo, которая вернет в том числе текущие координаты. Так что вполне можно сделать относительное перемещение.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов с курсором понятно , как сами значения затереть?

Comment: @its_space печать пробела определенно поможет.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Используйте `system("cls");` и выставление позиции до и после печати результатов. Вот Вам пример: после ввода 2 чисел и нажатия enter экран очищается, оставляя результаты и перенося позицию ввода в начало:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

void printResults(int result)
{
    HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO screenBuffer;
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hConsole, &screenBuffer);
    system("cls");
    COORD coordinates = {0, screenBuffer.dwCursorPosition.Y};
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsole, coordinates);
    cout << "Sum is: " << result << "\n";
    coordinates = {0, 0};
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsole, coordinates);
}

void main() 
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while(cin >> i >> j)
    {
        printResults(i + j);
    }
}
```